# How can I control dimensions of tables in R?

Tags: r, multidimensional-array

I am trying to understand how I can control in which order **R** tabulates a `data.frame`.

```
set.seed(123)
x<-sample(c(0,1),10,T)
y<-sample(c(0,1),10,T)
z<-sample(c(0,1),10,T)
test<-data.frame(x,y,z)
table(test)
```

The standard format is:

```
, , z = 0

   y
x   0 1
  0 0 1
  1 1 0

, , z = 1

   y
x   0 1
  0 0 3
  1 4 1
```

**R** tabulates in the order of appearance in the `data.frame`. But how can I get a tabulation conditional on the levels of `x,,` or `,y,` instead? Obviously `data.frame(z,y,x)` is an option, but I want to control this from the `table` function, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do with the result. The ftable function ('f' for flatten) offers an alternate way:

```
> ftable(test, row.vars=c(2,1), col.vars=3)
    z 0 1
y x      
0 0   0 0
  1   1 4
1 0   1 3
  1   0 1
```

Comment: +1 I think this comes closest to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the only way to control this directly from `table` is to change the order in which the variables appear. Another option would be to use `aperm`:

```
> aperm(table(test),perm = c(3,1,2))
, , y = 0

   x
z   0 1
  0 0 1
  1 0 4

, , y = 1

   x
z   0 1
  0 1 0
  1 3 1
```

Equivalently:

```
> table(test[,c(3,1,2)])
, , y = 0

   x
z   0 1
  0 0 1
  1 0 4

, , y = 1

   x
z   0 1
  0 1 0
  1 3 1
```